# Rails erb get value of a text_field_tag

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I have simple html.erb form like below

```
<table>
  <%= text_field_tag :tesintg %>
  <th><%= button_to 'Apply now', apply_product_index_path(:value => "Want Value of input in text field here") , method: :post %></th>
</table>
```

When "Apply now" button is pressed I want the value in the testing text_field_tag to be posted as query params as {"value" : "Value in the text field"}

How do I achieve this.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't wrap these elements in a form and let it do the work for you? That'd be the simplest solution. Otherwise, you'll need to use JavaScript.

Comment: Yeah it's easier just to use a traditional html form instead.  Alternatively you could use javascript to grab the value from the text field and inject it into the query params.

Comment: Sean how to do that. How can I use javascript to grab the value and use it in button_to line.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to do something like that is just to create `form_tag`

```
<%= form_tag apply_product_index_path, method: :post do %>
   <%= text_field_tag :teasing %>
   <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

This will pass to your controller hash `params: { teasing: 'value passed as teasing` }. You can easily use it from there with `params[:teasing]`.

You don't need to grab value from `text_field_tag` and put it into `button`.

Also remember that if you are creating new object, very ofter preferred way is to use `form_for` tag which uses specific model. I'm not sure what are your intentions, so i'm not going to rewrite everything that has already beed said. You can read much more in here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html